# Rails 4, capistrano error: cannot load such file -- deploy/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I've been following this railscast here on deploying to a VPS http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps and I seem to be stuck on on deploying. When I type in cap deploy, I get this.

```
cap aborted!
cannot load such file -- deploy/assets
/files/rails/Capfile:2:in `load'
/files/rails/Capfile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:22:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "(removed)", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "Fooddiscovery"
set :user, "(removed)"
set :deploy_to, "/home/rails"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "(removed)"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

My capfile

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace)
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy'
```

I read other questions and answers that said to add
if respond_to?(:namespace)
which did actually help with the first error where instead of deploy/assets, it use to show errors for just deploy ( cannot load such file -- deploy ). Putting in if respond_to?(:namespace) for all three links does not solve the issue. In fact a new error shows if I do that telling me undefined local variable or method `tasks_without_stage_dependency'.

Thanks!

Comment: did you work this out? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: @MichaelMoulsdale Unfortunately not. I haven't revisited this since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Michael's correct that you're using Capistrano 2 syntax with Capistrano 3, but you could just make sure you're using Capistrano 2 in your Gemfile for a quick fix.

```
gem 'capistrano', '2.15.5'
```

But if you're interested in using Capistrano 3, here is a pretty good [upgrade guide](https://semaphoreapp.com/blog/2013/11/26/capistrano-3-upgrade-guide.html) that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Capistrano 2 syntax in your Capfile, and you have upgraded to the Capistrano 3 gem.

Capistrano 3 looks more like the following in the Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/rails'
```